# Performance Analysis in PostgreSQL

Tags: c++, linux, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL with c++ and I am trying to analyse the performance of different queries. I tried using EXPLAIN ANALYZE but I can't figure out how to print the result on screen. How can I do so?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "print the result on screen". When running EXPLAIN ANALYZE, the result returned from the server will be the execution plan. So you'd print it as any other result you obtain through your SQL client. How exactly are you running the EXPLAIN? Which tool are you using?

Comment: I tried to print it with: res1 = PQexec(conn, explainQuery.c_str()); for (int i= 0; i < PQntuples(res1); i++)
 {
  for (int j = 0; j < nFields; j++)
  {
   temp_value = PQgetvalue(res1, i, j); 
   cout << temp_value;
  }
 }

Comment: Should work as it is "just a result" But I don't do C++, so I cannot tell for sure. Did you try it with psql?

Comment: It's weird but the same syntax seems to work now. I guess I messed up while declaring variables or something. Thanks though. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `psql` command-line tool will run queries and display the results.